# Online operation cannot be performed for index

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

I'm trying to REBUILD/REORGANIZE indexes on our SQL SERVER 2014 Enterprise db server.  I've written the following stored procedure with help from the web:

```
USE [ManagementReporter]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[REORGANIZE_TOP_INDEXES_NO_PAGE]
AS
    DECLARE @dbname            SYSNAME = DB_NAME(),
            @schema_name       SYSNAME,
            @page_count        INT,
            @table_name        SYSNAME,
            @index_name        SYSNAME,
            @avg_fragmentation FLOAT,
            @sql               NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- Do re-indexing
    DECLARE INDEXFRAGMENTATION CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
      SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5000 DBSCHEMAS.[NAME] AS 'Schema',
                      DBTABLES.[NAME] AS 'Table',
                      DBINDEXES.[NAME] AS 'Index',
                      INDEXSTATS.AVG_FRAGMENTATION_IN_PERCENT AS 'Frag %',
                      PAGE_COUNT
        FROM SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_PHYSICAL_STATS (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS INDEXSTATS
             INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES dbtables
                     ON DBTABLES.[OBJECT_ID] = INDEXSTATS.[OBJECT_ID]
             INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS dbschemas
                     ON DBTABLES.[SCHEMA_ID] = DBSCHEMAS.[SCHEMA_ID]
             INNER JOIN SYS.INDEXES AS DBINDEXES
                     ON DBINDEXES.[OBJECT_ID] = INDEXSTATS.[OBJECT_ID]
                    AND INDEXSTATS.INDEX_ID = DBINDEXES.INDEX_ID
             INNER JOIN SYS.INDEX_COLUMNS AS DBINDEXCOLUMNS
                     ON DBINDEXCOLUMNS.[OBJECT_ID] = DBINDEXES.[OBJECT_ID]
             INNER JOIN SYS.COLUMNS AS DBSYSCOLUMNS
                     ON DBSYSCOLUMNS.[OBJECT_ID] = DBINDEXCOLUMNS.[OBJECT_ID]
                    AND DBSYSCOLUMNS.COLUMN_ID = DBINDEXCOLUMNS.COLUMN_ID
       WHERE INDEXSTATS.DATABASE_ID = DB_ID()
         AND DBINDEXES.NAME IS NOT NULL
         AND NOT ( DBSYSCOLUMNS.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID IN ( 34, 35, 99, 173, 241 ) --IMAGE, TEXT, NTEXT, BINARY, XML
                    OR ( DBSYSCOLUMNS.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID IN ( 165, 167, 231 )  --VARBINARY, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR
                         AND DBSYSCOLUMNS.MAX_LENGTH = -1 ) )
       ORDER BY INDEXSTATS.AVG_FRAGMENTATION_IN_PERCENT DESC  

    OPEN INDEXFRAGMENTATION
    FETCH NEXT FROM INDEXFRAGMENTATION INTO @schema_name,
                                            @table_name,
                                            @index_name,
                                            @avg_fragmentation,
                                            @page_count

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
        IF @avg_fragmentation > 20 -- ReBuild index          
          SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX [' + @index_name + '] ON [' + @schema_name + '].[' + @table_name + '] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON (WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY (MAX_DURATION= 20, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT=BLOCKERS)))';
        ELSE -- ReOrganize index       
          SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX [' + @index_name + '] ON [' + @schema_name + '].[' + @table_name + '] REORGANIZE;';

        EXEC (@sql)        

        FETCH NEXT FROM INDEXFRAGMENTATION INTO @schema_name,
                                                @table_name,
                                                @index_name,
                                                @avg_fragmentation,
                                                @page_count
      END

    CLOSE INDEXFRAGMENTATION
    DEALLOCATE INDEXFRAGMENTATION
```

From what I've read on the WEB, I thought if I ignored the indexes with the above SYSTEM_TYPE_ID's, I thought it would not bring these indexes back in my result set.  However, the following Index is still getting selected and producing the following error:

> Msg 2725, Level 16, State 2, Line 3 An online operation cannot be
>   performed for index 'PK_ReportOutput' because the index contains
>   column 'EmailMessage' of data type text, ntext, image or FILESTREAM.
>   For a non-clustered index, the column could be an include column of
>   the index. For a clustered index, the column could be any column of
>   the table. If DROP_EXISTING is used, the column could be part of a new
>   or old index. The operation must be performed offline.

The EmailMessage column is defined as (ntext, not null), so I'm not understanding why it's getting selected with my main SQL above?  It looks like ntext has a system_type_id of 99, which I have excluded.

Here is the definition of the Table and Index that the error's complaining about:

[image]

Am I missing something with my SQL statement?

Comment: Sounds like the index might have multiple columns included in it, so it's getting included in your query because the NTEXT column gets filtered out but then the other column(s) in the index do not. Can you show the definition of PK_ReportOutput index?

Comment: Also even if this worked, you would likely have run your rebuilds / reorgs multiple times for a single index if that index had more than 1 column included in it.

Comment: I included a screenshot of the only index on that table and it just said: PK_ReportOutput (Clustered)

Comment: Right click on the index and do "Script Index As" -> "Create to" -> "New Query Editor Window" That will show the actual command that created the index

Comment: Surprise! Welcome to the wonderful world of clustered indexes. The fact is that a clustered index on a table that contains a field of text, ntext, image, etc. is simply unable to be reindexed online. The ntext field does not have to be part of the index. Note your error message: For a clustered index, the column could be **any column of the table.**

Comment: @LaughingVergil Has it right, I completely spaced on the fact it was a clustered index.

Comment: Do note, however, that if you convert the fields from ntext to nvarchar(max), I believe they will work.

Comment: Came across this thread because I'm having the same problem.  I think @LaughingVergil has answered it.